# Where to add axios interceptors code in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using vue js as frontend with laravel. I am using laravel passport for auth, now i wants to show some error message once received 401 unauthentic error message that mostly occurs when my token expired. so to do this i am using axios interceptors my code is like

`axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
      return response
    }, function (error) {
      // const { config, response: { status } } = error
      const { config, response } = error
      const originalRequest = config
      if (response && response.status === 401) {
           //notication or redirection
            this.$vs.notify({
            title: 'Error',
            text: response.data['message'],
            iconPack: 'feather',
            icon: 'icon-check-circle',
            color: 'danger'
            })
      }
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })`

Now Question is that **where i put this code in vue js** so that it call after every request & so an error message shown & redirect to login once get **401 unauthorized.**.

Any Suggestion from anyone.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

app.js or add them to separate file and include in app.js. There is post about this https://medium.com/@yaob/how-to-globally-use-axios-instance-and-interceptors-e28f351bb794